# What would I use to be able to click a link and have it display information on the same page as the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set one of my links up so that when it is clicked it will display some information. Currently the links and the information from the links display all at once. I would like to display the links first and then display the information from those links after the first link is clicked.

Here's my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function($) {
 // First link out of three
 var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog    
/items?parentId=504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
                 var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/";
                 var link = "";

                 $.each(json.items, function(i,item){
                     link = linkBase + this.id
                     $('#sbItems').append('<li><b><a href="' + link + '">' +     
this.title + '</a> - </b>' + this.summary + '</li>');            
                 });

             for (var i = 21; i < 22; i++) {
                     var urlId = json.items[i].id;
             }

                 var itemLnkId =  urlId;
                 //alert(itemLnkId);

                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'GET',
                     url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + 
itemLnkId + '?format=jsonp',
                     jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     dataType: 'jsonp',
                     success: function(json) {
                                  var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/
catalog/item/";
                                  var link = "";
                                  $.each(json, function(i,item){
                                      link = linkBase + this.relatedItemId
                                      $('#sbItems').append('<li><a href="' + 
link + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>');            
                                  });

                 for (var i = 19; i < 20; i++) {
                         var urlId = json.items[i].id;
                 }

                     var itemLnkId =  urlId;
                     //alert(itemLnkId);
                     },
                     error: function(e) {
                         console.log(e.message);
                     }
                 });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><em>This is a simple example of a basic HTML page that uses JQuery to call 
items from ScienceBase in JSON format and output them on the page. It serves 
to show how a basic web application can interact with dynamic ScienceBase 
services. The code points out the one critical feature of such an application, 
the use of a callback method in the Javascript to allow web pages on one domain 
to call and render JSON from another domain (www.sciencebase.gov). The listing 
below comes from a query for items under a particular ScienceBase parent item - 
a set of project records from the USGS National Research Program. The listing 
shows title with a link to the full project record in ScienceBase and summary 
(first part of a full abstract). View source for code examples and inline 
comments.</em></p>

<h3>Projects of the USGS Water National Research Program</h3>

<div class='wrapper'>
<ul id='sbItems'></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/XzRFu/
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see the text 'Hydrologic' anywhere in your sample page.  Is Hydrologic dynamically loaded with that AJAX call?  Try to set up JSFiddle with a valid example, even if you're ripping out the AJAX part and statically showing the markup.  It'll be helpful.

Comment: `for (var i = 21; i < 22; i++)` and `for (var i = 19; i < 20; i++)` !!!???

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Hey Eli, here's the jsfiddle link, [link]http://jsfiddle.net/XzRFu/ that's the first time I've set one up so I hope it works. The link is named "Hydrologic, Ecological, and Biogeochemical Processess in Flowing waters". If you click on it as of now it takes you to another webpage, but I would like the links that come up at the bottom of the jsfiddle example to display instead? Thanks

Comment: @machineghost, I set up a jsfiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/XzRFu/ and I'm trying to get the link named "Hydrologic, Ecological, and Biogeochemical Processess in Flowing waters" to display the citations at the bottom only when the link is clicked instead of going to another webpage.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I'm just doing some testing as of now and needed to get to that particular link because it's the only one that has citation links otherwise I couldn't display the information.

Comment: OK, that's called a "devHack". It's best to label defHacks with a commnent.

Comment: @jc72 That isn't really a question: you're not asking anyone for information, you're asking them to help you do your job for you.  Someone still might answer this (SO is a nice place), but a lot of people (like myself) will pass up this kind of question.  You'll have A LOT more success if you can rephrase your problem as a question of knowledge instead.

Comment: @machineghost, fair enough but that really wasn't my intention and I apologize if that's how my question was perceived. My question then is simply this, I currently know how to display the information coming from my links on to the webpage that's shown in the jsfiddle. The first part of the page display's links and the second part display's links that are actually citations. I jsut want to know how I could click one of the first set of links and then display the second set instead of going to another webpage. I did some research on using onclick but I'm not sure if that will work?

Comment: @machineghost, also I will change the question to be much simpler, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jc72,

Try this for size - based on your fiddle :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
#programs {
    margin: 12px 0;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#programs h2, #programs h3 {
    margin: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#programs ul {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
#programTemplate, #projectTemplate {
    display: none;
}
.summary {
    display: none;
}
.prog .p_loading,
.related .loading {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    function getData(url) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        });
    }

    var strings = {
        linkTemplate: 'http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/%s',
        programUrlTemplate: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?parentId=%s&max=60&offset=0&format=jsonp',
        urlTemplate: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/%s?format=jsonp',
        relatedLinkTemplate: '<a href="%s1">%s2</a>'
    };
    var $programTemplate = $("#programTemplate").find(".prog");
    var $projectTemplate = $("#projectTemplate").find(".project");

    function getProjects($program) {
        var $progContainer = $programTemplate.clone().insertAfter($program);
        var $ul = $progContainer.find(".program");
        var url = strings.programUrlTemplate.replace('%s', $program.attr('id'));
        $program.on('click', function() {
            if(!$program.data('served')) {
                $progContainer.show().find(".p_loading").show();
                getData(url).done(function(json) {
                    if(json.items.length) {
                        $.each(json.items, function(i, item) {
                            //if(i !== 21) return true;
                            var $project = $projectTemplate.clone().appendTo($ul);
                            var $title = $project.find(".title").text(item.title).on('click', function() {
                                $project.find(".summary").slideToggle();
                            });
                            $project.find(".text").html(this.summary);
                            //$project.find(".more").attr('href', strings.linkBase + item.id);
                            $project.find(".more").attr('href', strings.linkTemplate.replace('%s',item.id));
                            var $relatedUl = $project.find("ul.relatedLinks");
                            $project.find(".getRelated").on('click', function(e) {
                                var $this = $(this);
                                if(!$this.data('served')) {
                                    $project.find(".loading").show();
                                    getData(strings.urlTemplate.replace('%s', item.id)).done(function(json2) {
                                        if(json2.length) {
                                            $.each(json2, function(j, item2) {
                                                $("<li/>").appendTo($relatedUl).append($(strings.relatedLinkTemplate.replace('%s1', strings.linkBase + item2.relatedItemId).replace('%s2', item2.title)));
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $("<li>None</li>").appendTo($relatedUl);
                                        }
                                        $relatedUl.slideDown('slow');
                                        $project.find(".loading").hide();
                                    });
                                    $this.data('served', true);
                                }
                                else{
                                    $relatedUl.slideToggle('slow');
                                }
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("<li>None</li>").appendTo($ul);
                    }
                    $ul.slideDown('slow');
                    $progContainer.find(".p_loading").hide();
                });
                $program.data('served', true);
            }
            else {
                $ul.slideToggle('slow');
            }
        });
    }

    $("h2.program").each(function(i, program) {
        getProjects( $(program) );
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="programTemplate">
    <div class="prog">
        <div class="p_loading">Loading ...</div>
        <ul class="program"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="projectTemplate">
    <li class="project">
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <div class="summary">
            <div>
                <span class="text"></span>
                <span><a class="more" href="" target="_new">more ...</a></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="getRelated">Related links ...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="related">
                <div class="loading">Loading ...</div>
                <ul class="relatedLinks"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<p><em>This is a simple example of a basic HTML page that uses JQuery to call items from ScienceBase in JSON format and output them on the page. It serves to show how a basic web application can interact with dynamic ScienceBase services. The code points out the one critical feature of such an application, the use of a callback method in the Javascript to allow web pages on one domain to call and render JSON from another domain (www.sciencebase.gov). The listing below comes from a query for items under a particular ScienceBase parent item - a set of project records from the USGS National Research Program. The listing shows title with a link to the full project record in ScienceBase and summary (first part of a full abstract). View source for code examples and inline comments.</em></p>

<div id="programs">
    <h2 class="program" id="504108e5e4b07a90c5ec62d4">Projects of the USGS Water National Research Program</h2>
    <!-- add other programs here -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gz83a/3/show/)**

It needs beautifying somewhat with better CSS but the essential functionality is there.

Comment: WOW, Beetroot-Beetroot that's one hell of an example haha. That is way more than I needed but more than answers my question too! I've kind of gone in the direction of using $(document.on('click','#sbItems a', function(e)) etc, which I see you have something similar in there also with some extra functionality. Anyway, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jc, yeah I got carried away trying to make the whole thing usable with collapsible sections. In case you haven't worked it out, ajax is performed "on demand" at two levels - *programs* and *related links*, thereby easing the load on the server. To add more programs just add further `<h2 class="program" id="...">xxx</h2>` elements to the #programs div; the code will sense them and attach the necessary click handler.

Comment: Overall the code could be tidier. There's probably a way to simplify the structure which is essentially one  structure nested inside a very similar structure. With a liitle more time I'm sure I could make something much more readable.